# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [interface org.springframework.test.context.TestContextBootstrapper]

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I had some dependencies problem in my springboot project and I solved them. I was getting this error:

TestContextBootstrapper [null]

And now I get this error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [interface org.springframework.test.context.TestContextBootstrapper].`

While trying to run junit test for my controller class.

There isn't any information about this specific information that I find on the internet, only with null. Is there something I should look for?

**Update:** Adding the following line before my class solved my issue: `@BootstrapWith(value= SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)`

Comment: Which clearly means you haven't fixed your dependency problem. Looks like you are trying to outsmart the spring boot dependency management and have included a bunch on incompatible versions of jars. Add your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` to see what you did.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you feedback but I found the solution, for anyone having similar issue adding the following line before my class did the trick: @BootstrapWith(value= SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)